# Nonlinear system with time-optimal control

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, optimal-control, nonlinear-control, adaptive-control

Given nonlinear system:

\begin{cases} \dot{x_1}=x_3+u \\ \dot{x_2}=-x_2+\dot{f} \\ \dot{x_3}=-x_3+x_2 \cdot \alpha \sin(\omega t) \\ \dot{x_4}=-x_4+x_2 \cdot (\frac{16}{\alpha^2}(\sin(\omega t)-\frac{1}{2})) \end{cases}

where, $x_1...x_4$ - variables;

$f=-(x_1+\alpha \sin(\omega t))^2$;

$\alpha, \omega >0$ - constants.

**Problem:** make variable $x_4$ negative in minimal time

How to formulate the criterion for the optimal time?

I would be grateful for advice and help.

**EDIT**
There is my code, where i try to used [FeedbackLinearize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FeedbackLinearize.html)

```
Clear["Derivative"]
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Needs["Parallel`Developer`"]

S[t] = \[Alpha] Sin[\[Omega] t]; 
M[t] = 16/\[Alpha]^2 (( Sin[\[Omega] t])^2 - 1/2);

f = -(x1[t] + S[t] - xe)^2

Parallelize[
 asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{x1'[t] == x3[t] + u[t], 
     x2'[t] + x2[t] == D[f, t] + x3[t], x3'[t] + x3[t] == x2[t] S[t], 
     x4'[t] + x4[t] == x2[t] M[t]}, {{x1[t], xs}, {x2[t], 0}, {x3[t], 
      0}}, {u[t]}, {(x4[t])}, t] // Simplify]

\[ScriptCapitalF] = 
  FeedbackLinearize[
   asys, {{Subscript[z, 1], Subscript[z, 2], Subscript[z, 3], 
     Subscript[z, 4]}, v}];

\[ScriptCapitalF]["ResidualSystem"] // Simplify

pars = {xs = -1, xe = 1, \[Alpha] = 0.35, \[Omega] = 2 Pi*1/2, k = 100}

OutputResponse[{asys, {xs, 0, 0, 0}}, 0, {t, 0, 100}]
Plot[%, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]

\[ScriptCapitalF]["LinearSystem"] // Simplify

\[Kappa] = 
 StateFeedbackGains[\[ScriptCapitalF]["LinearSystem"], {-1, -1}]

csys = \[ScriptCapitalF][{"ClosedLoopSystem", \[Kappa]}]

sr = StateResponse[{csys, {xs, 0, 0, 0}}, {0}, {t, 0, 250}];
Plot[#, {t, 0, 250}, PlotRange -> All] & /@ %[[{1, 4}]]
```

*I didn't succeed, a system with such an arrangement of inputs contains a singular ResidualDynamic.*

Comment: You might get more answers for this type of thing at the [Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I must disappoint you in the fact that my knowledge in non-linear control is very limited. Even though I can guess that something like $u(t) = -x_3 - x_1 + c$ where $c$ is some constant will steer $x_1$ to $c$. Knowing what $f$ looks like, this can be used to keep $x_4$ less than zero. However, I do not know how to assert any performance properties. Luckily, with your provide model, I think someone with some knowledge in non-linear control might help you. Good luck :D

Comment: Have you tried to implement either input-output linearization or full state linearization ? Both considering your output to be $y = x_4$ cause you basically want to control this state. And also what does make $x_4$ negative mean ? Like $x_4 = -100$, $x_4 = -10000 $ or $x_4 = -1$ ? Do you have any more specific reference for $x_4$ ?

Comment: Could we maybe introduce a specific requirement for $x_4$ ? Because you want it to be negative, we can demand it to track the reference signal $r(t) = -1, \forall t > 0$ ?

Comment: @TeoProtoulis

1. I tried the https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/nonlinear-control-systems/asymptotic-output-tracking.html. I have not tried it separately, because I'm afraid to turn the system into a "dummy" integrator and lose its important properties.

2. Could we maybe introduce a specific requirement for $x_4$. Yes, but these must be the requirements of the species: $sign(x_4)=-1$ or $tanh(k x_4)=-1$ or $sign(x_4)+1=0$ or $tanh(k x_4)+1=0$, where $k >> 1$

Comment: @TeoProtoulis Have you heard anything about the funnel control?  https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.10123

Comment: @Petrus1904 Have you heard anything about the funnel control?  https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.10123